# How to use tab for indent in indent function while expand tab was set?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, indent

When `expandtab` is set, how to let the indent function defined in file `vim/indent/xxx.vim` use tabs, rather than spaces to indent lines?

#### Edit:

Here is the background. I have use vim's built-in `CHANGELOG` syntax to write some change log, using a tab to indent but use spaces to align (`|------>` means a tab):

```
1.0.1 - 2021-03-21  lxvs

|------>* BUGFIX: some-bug...
|------>* IMPROVEMENT: quite a long long long
|------>               improvement.
```

I want to let vim auto format the line 5 as shown above by means of the indent function and thought of a workaround that let the line indent one less space and insert a tab into the begining of the line:

```
function! ClogIndent(lnum)
    let l:prevlnum = prevnonblank(a:lnum-1)
    if l:prevlnum == 0
        return 0
    endif

    let l:prevl = getline(l:prevlnum)
    let l:thisl = getline(a:lnum)
    let l:previ = indent(l:prevlnum)

    let l:ind = l:previ

    if l:thisl =~ '\*\s\a\+:\s'
        return l:ind
    endif

    if l:prevl =~ '\*\s\a\+:\s'
        if matchstr(l:thisl, '\%1c.') !~ '\t'
            call setline(a:lnum, substitute(l:thisl, '^', '\t', ""))
        endif
        let l:word = match(l:prevl, '\(\*\s\a\+:\s\)\@<=\w')
        let l:ind = l:word - 1
    endif

    return l:ind
endfunction
```

I'm quite sure that `call setline(a:lnum, substitute(l:thisl, '^', '\t', ""))` was called, but it seems has no effect. Howevert, it works well when typed manually. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The question is invalid. Maybe XY problem or something.

If `&indentexpr` is set to some function then that function calculates on-the-fly the number of spaces to indent a line. If also `&expandtab` is not set then Vim is allowed to minimize that number by outputting tabs - one hard tab per `&tabstop` spaces.

But if you `set expandtab` then you say: "I don't want any hard tabs to be auto-generated" and so whenever Vim is told to fill in some space (no matter if beginning or middle of a line) it outputs only spaces one by one.

UPD.

1. `indentexpr` is calculated right before reformatting a line. Hence your attempt to `setline` from within it is invalid.
2. I still don't see why it's so important to have "exactly one hard tab" at a beginning of a line. Say, simply having `setl noet` will only differ in "improvement" indented by two or three tabs and, maybe, few spaces. Doesn't look too bad, IMO.
3. It's possible to `setl et` and force replace of leading spaces by a tab upon `autocmd BufWrite` or even by manual typing appropriate `:%s` command. Looks ugly to me, but such stuff always works.
4. Another option is to `setl copyindent` (and also probably `setl preserveindent`), so Vim would try to replicate indent structure of a previous line. And so `copyindent` practically gets a preference over `expandtab` if previous line already has tab(s). The drawback is that every time you start a new paragraph, you have to force the very first hard tab manually (`<c-v><tab>`).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and sorry for the confusion. I edited my question. Do you have any idea?